# Celery multiple queues not working properly. All the tasks are sent to default queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, celery

I'm using Celery with a Flask application, and here is my config:

```
app.config['CELERY_TASK_QUEUES'] = (
    Queue('fast', Exchange('fast'), routing_key='fast'),
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('processing', Exchange('processing'), routing_key='processing'),
)

app.config['CELERY_TASK_ROUTES'] = {
    'app.tasks.extract_text': {'queue': 'processing', 'routing_key': 'processing'},
    ...

    'app.tasks.vt_notifications': {'queue': 'default', 'routing_key': 'default'},
    ...

    'app.tasks.update_files_from_search': {'queue': 'fast', 'routing_key': 'fast'},
    ...
}


app.config['CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE'] = 'default'
app.config['CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE'] = 'default'
app.config['CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY'] = 'default'
```

I ended up with running celery instances like this:

```
celery -A app.tasks.celery worker -Q 'processing' --concurrency 1 -l debug -n processing
celery -A app.tasks.celery worker -Q 'fast' --concurrency 1 -l debug -n fast
celery -A app.tasks.celery worker -Q 'default' --concurrency 1 -l debug -n default
```

So, the problem is that all the tasks are being sent to 'default' queue. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: celery version?

Answer (score 4):

If using celery >4, I would recommend few things:
First, try to add `name` to 
your task (to ensure you are using the right name in `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES`. For example:

```
@app.task(name='extract_text'])
    def extract_text(..):
        pass
```

Second, try to change the `CELERY_TASK_ROUTES` to:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'extract_text': {
        'exchange': 'processing',
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'processing'
    }
}
```

(instead of `queue` - try to add `exchange` and `exchange_type`).

Last thing, you don't have to use it, just for debugging, you can explicitly route task when triggering:

```
(extract_text.signature(args=(...), queue='processing')).delay()
```

**EDIT:**

are you sure you are using config as needed? here is an example:

```
celery_app = Celery()
celeryconfig = {}
celeryconfig['BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://'
celeryconfig['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost'
celeryconfig['CELERY_QUEUES'] = (
    Queue('fast', Exchange('fast'), routing_key='fast'),
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
    Queue('processing', Exchange('processing'), routing_key='processing'),
)
celeryconfig['CELERY_ROUTES'] = {
    'extract_text': {
        'exchange': 'processing',
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'processing'
    }
}

celery_app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

Comment: If I explicitly route task when triggering, it works perfectly. Looks like CELERY_TASK_ROUTES variable is just being ignored

Comment: did you try `CELERY_ROUTES` instead? maybe you not using config as needed, i'll update my answer in a second

Comment: I ended up by using @task(queue='queue_name') decorator